# Can I create custom Class in Android studio with parameters provided by user , to store data in Firebase RT DB

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase in Android studio for creating Tailoring app.
I want to offer feature to user that he can **create custom Item** like *shirt, trousers, jackets* where user can provide some types of measurements like **Height, Chest, Thigh** and by that I can create custom class of that Item with values and display it in front of user every time he wants to create new order for customer...

BTW I am using firebase realtime db to store values

```
DatabaseReference rootRef;

rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

Object itemObject = new Object(string1, string2);

rootRef.child("item").setValue(itemObject);
```

This object is coming from class created for that item.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a pojo class:

```
public class Items {

   String type;
   int height;

   public Items() {
   }

   public String getType() {
      return this.type;
   }
   public void setType(String value) {
      this.type = value;
   }
   public int getHeight() {
      return this.height;
   }
   public void setHeight(int value) {
      this.height = value;
   }
}
```

Then you can add the  object to the firebase database:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef;
rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Items itemObject = new Items("shirt", 20);
String key = rootRef.push().getKey();
rootRef.child(key).setValue(itemObject);
```

Comment: I am currently doing this. But the parameters of this class are fixed e.g.type, height. But the items created by user need to have fields created by him, we can't predefine those fields. Is there any way we can create that class with parameters provided by user.